# me podrian asistir con un error en python

Tags: python, windows, arduino

```
raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port '\\.\\COM6': PermissionError(13, 'Acceso denegado.', None, 5)
```

es la conexion de python con arduino para con codigo de python se prenda un led en arduin

tengo una practica en donde con python y arduino tengo que prender un led y utilizo la libreria pyfirmata para que con arduino se conecta para la declaración de led y en python hace la funcionabilidad para prender el led mandando un valor numerico o una letra y espero que cuando ejecute el código de python se prenda el led

Comment: Probablemente estás tratando de abrir una puerta privilegiada (bajo 1024). Sin ver el código fuente, es puro adivinar.

Comment: Hola DarkGoattt, bienvenido, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y de paso evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Y de paso, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 0):

La biblioteca `pyfirmata` se utiliza para establecer una conexión entre Python y Arduino, lo que permite a Python controlar los pines de entrada y salida de Arduino. En este caso, se está tratando de prender un LED conectado a Arduino mediante un código escrito en Python.

Prueba con esto:

```
import pyfirmata
import time

board = pyfirmata.Arduino("COM6")
led = board.get_pin("d:3:o")

while True:
    led.write(1)
    time.sleep(1)
    led.write(0)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Este código primero importa las bibliotecas `pyfirmata` y `time`. Luego, se establece una conexión con el puerto serial de Arduino a través de la función pyfirmata. Arduino("COM6"). La línea `led = board.get_pin("d:3:o")` se utiliza para obtener el pin digital 3 en modo de salida y asignarlo a la variable led.

Finalmente, el código entra en un bucle while infinito donde escribe un valor de 1 en el pin de salida (prendiendo el LED) y espera 1 segundo. Luego, escribe un valor de 0 en el pin de salida (apagando el LED) y espera otro segundo. Este proceso se repite indefinidamente hasta que se detenga el programa.

No se te olvide ajustar el nombre del puerto serial y el número de pin adecuados a su configuración específica.

Espero que te sirva, saludos